# Android Permission not Applying

Tags: java, android

Hope You all having a good day, I am learning android and i'm creating an application that scans for Wifi networks. The code makes sense and i seem to have the permissions correctly yet no permissions are being requested at all. Could you help me to figure out why aren't the permissions being granted? Am I missing anything ? Here is my code:

main activity.java:

```
package com.example.x.wifilocator;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
private TextView tv;
List<ScanResult> scanList;
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWifiNetworks);
    checkpermission();
}
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void checkpermission() {
    int hasWiFi =  checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    if (hasWiFi != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        Toast.makeText(this,"No Permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
    getWifiNetworksList();
}
private void getWifiNetworksList(){
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    final WifiManager wifiManager =
            (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);;
    registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @SuppressLint("UseValueOf") @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            scanList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
            sb.append("\n  Number Of Wifi connections :" + " " +scanList.size()+"\n\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < scanList.size(); i++){
                sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ". ");
                sb.append((scanList.get(i)).toString());
                sb.append("\n\n");
            }

            tv.setText(sb);
        }

    },filter);
    wifiManager.startScan();
}
}
```

Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--Permissions -->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: How do you know the permission is not granted?

Comment: Have you faced it for all devices?

Comment: @Jeffrey shouldn't  the device require them on runtime?  I am using lollipop in the tests.  Plus it isn't showing  a result of zero so what could be the problem?

Comment: I've tested  the apk on 3 device and an emulator all showed the same result.